# Не могу получить доступ к файлам сайта через Filezilla

Tags: администрирование

FileZilla выдаёт ошибку следующего содержания Econnrefused соединение отклонено сервером. Причём нет доступа с любого компа с файлзиллы любой версии.

Comment: Проверьте данные хоста и имя пользователя в файлзилле, возможно в них ошибка

Comment: нет в них ошибки. я всегда их копипастил из одного и того же источника, и до вчерашнего дня все работало

Comment: Попробуйте любой другой фтп клиент. Это даст ответ на вопрос - проблема в сервере или нкт

Comment: только что попробовал FTP-rush, тоже выдает ошибку(

Comment: Сервер удаленный? Логин/Пароль по ftp могли поменять только Вы? К серверу есть доступ по ssh?